# What is nio.js?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I am seeing an unknown script being displayed on all pages hosted on my site. This was not added by me to any of the pages, so i am assuming the hosting company is adding it on the fly when a page is requested.

This is what is added to the the page

```
    <script>
    ! function(n, e, i, o, t) {
        'use strict';
        if (!n.nio) {
            n.nio = function() {
                n.nio.execAction ? n.nio.execAction.apply(window.nio, arguments) : n.nio.queue.push(arguments)
            }, n.nio.push = n.nio, n.nio.loaded = !0, n.nio.version = '1.0', n.nio.queue = [];
            var s = e.createElement(i);
            s.async = !0, s.src = o;
            var r = e.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(s, r)
        }
    }(window, document, 'script', '//cdn.narrative.io/js/nio-js/v1.1/nio.js');
    nio('init', 9);
</script>
<noscript><img height='1' width='1' style='display:none' src='https://io.narrative.io?noscript=1&id=9'/></noscript>
```

This is what the nio.js file contains.

```
! function(t, e, n, r, i) {
    "use strict";
    var o, a, u = "__nio";
    if (!t.nio || 1 !== t.nio.libLoaded) {
        var s = function() {
                return "//" + r
            },
            c = function(t) {
                var e = typeof t;
                return "object" === e && "function" !== e && null !== t
            };
        o = "undefined" != typeof JSON && null !== JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify : function() {
            var t = Object.prototype.toString,
                e = Array.isArray || function(e) {
                    return "[object Array]" === t.call(e)
                },
                n = {
                    '"': '\\"',
                    "\\": "\\\\",
                    "\b": "\\b",
                    "\f": "\\f",
                    "\n": "\\n",
                    "\r": "\\r",
                    "   ": "\\t"
                },
                r = function(t) {
                    return n[t] || "\\u" + (t.charCodeAt(0) + 65536).toString(16).substr(1)
                },
                i = /[\\"\u0000-\u001F\u2028\u2029]/g;
            return function o(n) {
                if (null == n) return "null";
                if ("number" == typeof n) return isFinite(n) ? n.toString() : "null";
                if ("boolean" == typeof n) return n.toString();
                if ("object" == typeof n) {
                    if ("function" == typeof n.toJSON) return o(n.toJSON());
                    if (e(n)) {
                        for (var a = "[", u = 0; u < n.length; u++) a += (u ? ", " : "") + o(n[u]);
                        return a + "]"
                    }
                    if ("[object Object]" === t.call(n)) {
                        var s = [];
                        for (var c in n) n.hasOwnProperty(c) && s.push(o(c) + ": " + o(n[c]));
                        return "{" + s.join(", ") + "}"
                    }
                }
                return '"' + n.toString().replace(i, r) + '"'
            }
        }();
        var f = Object.assign || function(t) {
                if (t === i || null === t) throw new TypeError("Cannot convert undefined or null to object");
                for (var e = Object(t), n = 1; n < arguments.length; n++) {
                    var r = arguments[n];
                    if (r !== i && null !== r)
                        for (var o in r) r.hasOwnProperty(o) && (e[o] = r[o])
                }
                return e
            },
            l = function(t) {
                var e, n = [];
                for (var r in t) t.hasOwnProperty(r) && (e = c(t[r]) ? o(t[r]) : t[r], n.push(encodeURIComponent(r) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(e)));
                return n.join("&")
            },
            p = "addEventListener" in e,
            h = p ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
            d = p ? "removeEventListener" : "detachEvent",
            m = function(t, e, n) {
                e = p ? e : "on" + e;
                var r = function(i) {
                    t[d](e, r, !1), n(i)
                };
                t[h](e, r, !1)
            },
            v = {
                _isFiring: !1,
                numOfRequests: 0,
                addQueue: function(t) {
                    this.queue = this.queue.concat(t)
                },
                queue: [],
                isEmpty: function() {
                    return 0 === this.queue.length
                },
                complete: function(t) {
                    return t || this.queue.shift(), this._isFiring = !1, this._fire()
                },
                _fire: function() {
                    if (0 !== this.queue.length) {
                        var t = this.queue[0],
                            e = t[0] + "?" + l(t[1]);
                        return this._isFiring = !0, this.numOfRequests++, e.length > 2048 ? this.fireForm(t[0], t[1]) : this.fireImage(e)
                    }
                },
                request: function() {
                    return this.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)), this._isFiring ? this._isFiring : this._fire()
                },
                fireForm: function(t, n) {
                    var r = this,
                        i = "nio" + Math.random().toString().replace("0.", ""),
                        a = e.createElement("form"),
                        u = e.attachEvent && !e.addEventListener,
                        s = u ? '<iframe name="' + i + '">' : "iframe",
                        f = e.createElement(s);
                    a.method = "post", a.action = t, a.target = i, a.acceptCharset = "utf-8", a.style.display = "none", f.src = "javascript:false", f.id = i, f.name = i, a.appendChild(f), m(f, "load", function() {
                        var t, i = function(t) {
                            var e = c(t) ? t.type : null;
                            return a.parentNode.removeChild(a), r.complete("load" !== e)
                        };
                        for (var u in n) n.hasOwnProperty(u) && (t = e.createElement("input"), t.name = u, t.value = c(n[u]) ? o(n[u]) : n[u], a.appendChild(t));
                        m(f, "load", i), m(f, "error", i), a.submit()
                    }), e.body.appendChild(a)
                },
                fireImage: function(t) {
                    var e = new Image,
                        n = this,
                        r = function() {
                            n.complete()
                        };
                    return e.onload = r, e.onerror = r, e.src = t, t
                }
            },
            g = {
                companyId: null,
                options: {
                    forceSSL: !1,
                    forcePost: !1
                },
                getStandardVars: function() {
                    return {
                        companyId: this.companyId,
                        ret: "img",
                        ts: (new Date).valueOf()
                    }
                },
                errors: [],
                error: function(t) {
                    this.errors.push(t)
                },
                init: function(t, e) {
                    this.companyId = t, this.config(e)
                },
                config: function(t) {
                    for (var e in t) t.hasOwnProperty(e) && (this.options[e] === i && g.error("Narrative.io: " + e + " is not a valid config option"), this.options[e] = t[e])
                },
                data: function(t) {
                    return this.submit(t)
                },
                submit: function(t) {
                    var e = s();
                    e = (this.options.forceSSL ? "https:" : n.protocol) + e;
                    var r = f({}, this.getStandardVars(), t);
                    return v.request(e, r)
                }
            };
        t.nio._debug = function() {
            return [g, v, a]
        }, t.nio.execAction = function(t) {
            var e = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
            switch (t) {
                case "init":
                    return g.init.apply(g, e);
                case "data":
                    return g.data.apply(g, e);
                default:
                    return g.error("Narrative.io: " + t + " is not a valid action")
            }
        }, t.nio.libLoaded = !0, t.nio.libVersion = "1.0", t.nio.isValid = function() {
            return 0 === g.errors.length
        };
        for (var y = t.nio.queue.slice(), S = 0; S < y.length; S++) t.nio.execAction.apply(t.nio, y[S]);
        if (y.length = 0, a = null, t.sessionStorage) {
            a = function() {
                !v.isEmpty() && c(JSON) && "function" == typeof JSON.parse && t.sessionStorage.setItem(u, o(v.queue))
            }, m(t, "beforeunload", a, !1);
            var b = t.sessionStorage.getItem(u);
            if (null !== b) try {
                b = JSON.parse(b), v.addQueue(b)
            } catch (O) {
                g.error("Narrative.io: " + O.message)
            } finally {
                t.sessionStorage.removeItem(u)
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function(t, e) {
            return function() {
                0 === e.numOfRequests && t.execAction("data")
            }
        }(t.nio, v), 250)
    }
}(window, document, location, "io.narrative.io");
```

I am trying to understand what this script intends to do. Google search did not yield any useful information, and the company hosting the js file does not have much information on it. Hoping to get some javascript expert make sense of this.

Comment: Found this [here](https://angel.co/narrative-i-o): Narrative is building a platform to support modern businesses who want to buy and/or sell their data assets. The thesis is that there is a burgeoning data economy that is being held back by lack of tooling and massive inefficiencies around discovery, pricing/value, and delivery of the data. We're building out a platform that helps eliminate those inefficiencies.

Comment: Little to find, apart from that description Technotronic gave. Their website is also non-descriptive, and they have a twitter account with hardly any activity or followers. If you didn't add this or add a library that uses this, I'd check with your hosting company. Or ask [the CEO](https://www.linkedin.com/in/nickjordan). Anyway, looks like the one who put it there is making money of your website.

Comment: Thanks, i have opened a ticket with my hosting company to find out if they can provide more information.

Comment: The hosting company is unaware of this, i checked other websites on the same shared ip address and even they have it. Hosting company thinks it is some kind of code injection.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved. The hosting company did some more digging and found out from their development team that this was part of a pilot program to collect some analytics data.